# Adding observations to training set makes it worse. Is that because of noise?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, variance, predictive-models

**Situation**

I am fitting a model on a training set. Now I pick the parameters so that they minimize the Cross-Validation score (in python `cross_val_score`), but it is not important how I am doing this.

I started with a training set of size around 80. The parameters of my model are 5.

Now, doing this training, then I try to predict for 38k observations.

**Problem**
for size = 370, I get a Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) of 0.0023
if I increase the training set size, I see that:

for size=740 I get RMSE 0.0025

for size=1480 I get RMSE 0.0026

In summary, as I increase the training set, my RMSE increases. Also, I have tried using the whole set of 37k observations as my training set. In this case I can see by plotting that the predictions are super biased, but with small variance.

**Summary**

As I increase training set size: RMSE increases, Bias Increases, Variance decreases.

What does this mean? I read somewhere that as the flexibility of a model increases, then the variance increases and the variance decreases. Does this mean that as I increase the training set size, my model becomes less flexible?

I cannot give you a MWE since the code and the rest is super messy..

Comment: There are many possible explanations: 
(1) Are the differences in RMSE really significant?
(2) Maybe the model is too simple and cannot deal with more data?
You can check the second case my looking at your training set error, does it increase or decrease with more data?

Comment: With more data, the error increases

Comment: It could be that the model cannot keep up with the data (it is too simple, i.e. has high bias). When you increase the training data how do you select examples? Are they completely new or extend the smaller training set? I will suggest that the larger training set should be a superset of the smaller ones (i.e. progressive sampling) and then repeat the procedure such that the there is variability in the way you sample. If you still see similar patterns then it is more likely the case that you need a more complex model (for example by adding interaction terms).